# Pycharm turn off HTML tag creation while in Live Template

Tags: pycharm, live-templates

I created a simple live template called `href`:

```
<a href="$href$">$text$</a>$END$
```

Order is `$text$` then `$href$` but after filling in the `$text$` variable and pressing TAB instead of jumping to `$href$` it instead creates an html tag. For example when I type "menu" then TAB:

```
<a href=""><menu></menu></a>
```

Is there a way to turn off the tag creation part while in a live template in Pycharm Community Ed?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions:

1. Change the order of variables `$href$` and `$text$`, so when you press tab after href it will automatically jump to text variable.

   [image: Live template]
2. Because menu is already defined in context of Emmet I think, you can change you live template to expand on <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> (right bottom at top picture)

   Example using <kbd>Enter</kbd> on expand and using again <kbd>Enter</kbd> to jump between template variables:

   [image: Live template]